# How to delete old-school program from windows7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, uninstall, compatibility

I just installed [Ext2 Installable File System 1.11a](http://www.fs-driver.org/download.html), it creates new drive in "My computer" like link to my ext3 partition but further it does not work for me - an error appears when I try to access this drive (this program actually not for Windows 7) and now I want to remove it, but there is no appropriate menu entry in "Remove programms" window.

And no folder in "Program files"

So, how to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing it again, but before running the installer, right click on Properties and change the compatibility mode to Windows XP SP3.  After this, check if it now appears in the Programs and Features control panel.

Comment: Tnanks, but I this you dont understand me - I already selected id when I installed it first time, except that it was SP2 as windows suggested to me.

Comment: selected "it" i mean

Comment: dont sure what exactly helped - your suggestion or that I rebooted, but now it appeared in Uninstall menu, thanks:)

Comment: The information on uninstallation may be founded on program's Web site: http://www.fs-driver.org/faq.html#uninstall including details about installed files (.sys. exe and so on) and this mention: « Use the "Add/Remove Programs" item in the control panel to uninstall the "Ext2 IFS 1.11a for Windows" software.

Note: Uninstallation will require a reboot. »